# Basic SQL UDF creation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

After reading far too much on the subject, I'm clueless how to write a UDF, and where to save it.

Instead of writing the same nested REPLACE() numerous times in several other scripts, I would like to be able to call it as I need, something like:

```
Targ.Name =  dbo.fn_add_sym( isnull(Targ.Name,  Src.Name) )
```

I have the following function, but I haven't been able to test it, since I don't know where to put it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_add_sym( @string NVARCHAR(max) )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
begin
return 
  @string = REPLACE(
              REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                      REPLACE(@string, N'%2b', N'+')
                    , N'%2d', N'-')
                  , N'%3d', N'=')
                , N'%22', N'"')
              , N'%5f', N'_')
            ,'&quot;', N'"')

end
```

Comment: You tagged your question with both MySQL and SQL Server. Which one is it?

Comment: How exactly do you want to use it?

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because the query appears to be SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Yes, I've been using Express 2012, but I want to convert over to MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5b4ee/1) is a SQL Fiddle that shows the function.

The following is some code to test it:

```
select dbo.fn_add_sym('abc%5fdef')
```

The only syntax error you had was `return @string =`.  The `@string =` is unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you!  The bit that I was missing was that I had to execute the function by itself to add it to the db!  DOH!!!!! :)